# What's the effect of declaring List instead of ICollection in Code First EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

Usually, when I declare a one-to-many relationship I'll use *ICollection*, as follows.

```
public class Thong
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}

public class Thing
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Thong Thong { get; set; }
}
```

That's done automatically, without considering what-if's and such. However, I started to think now and I can't really tell what the following alteration would change in the setup. I've run the migrations on it but as far I can tell, there's no difference in the DB.

```
model.Entity<Thing>()
  .HasRequired(_ => _.Thong)
  .WithMany(_ => _.Things)
  .Map(_ => _.MapKey("ThongId"));

public class Thong
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public List<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}

public class Thing
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Thong Thong { get; set; }
}
```

One thing that I suspect is that I just killed lazy loading so all the instances of related things will be served for each retrieval of a thong. Is it so? I'm pretty certain it is.

My actual question is what else that's going to change except of the list being populated eagerly now.

Comment: I think if you have change tracking enabled it will make no difference, entity framework will replace either with EntityCollection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring your property as `ICollection<T>` or `List<T>` has nothing in common with lazy loading - it's the `virtual` modifier that controls whether your property can be lazy loaded or not.

The difference is that by declaring the property to be a `List<T>`, you are forcing the EF to create and populate a **concrete** class (or class derived from that concrete class) when loading your entity (either lazy or eager). While when declared as `ICollection<T>`, EF can populate it with some internal data structure, `T[]`, `HashSet<T>` etc. i.e. whatever class that implements `ICollection<T>`.

For instance, using your variant with `ICollection`, try something like this

```
var result = db.Thong.Include(thong => thong.Things).ToList();
```

and examine the `Things` member actual type. You'll see that it's a `HashSet<Thing>`, not `List<Thing>`.

Comment: In addition to this, one may prefer explicitly declaring a `List<T>` because the richer API (like `AddRange`, `Insert`, ...) fits better with specific business logic.

Comment: @GertArnold That's along those lines I started to think about it but rejected the advantages as too weak compared to potential oopsies and gotchas, since nobody else does it that way, as far I've seen.

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, it's not something I'd advocate. If I need a specific collection implementation I setup a view- or domain model. For others it may be a viable option though.